How to compile for Linux when on Windows using Code::Blocks?
I have a console app which I want to compile for Linux.
I don't have access to a Linux operating system at the moment, but I really do need to compile this program for as many operating systems as possible.
I do have a basic idea of what Linuxes are and that they have different bases, but I have no idea on how to compile for them.
And I have made this C++ application on Code::Blocks, so I would like to know how to compile for Linux.
The easiest way or better say the most efficient.
I want to compile the program for both RPM- and Debian-based Linux.

I would run Linux in a VM

Path of least resistance would be to spin up Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) and make your own sort-of linux box. Alternative is to track down a cross compiler and configure Code::Blocks to use the cross compiler rather than your usual Windows build tools.

Check the project-options. There is the option to select the build targets. There should an option "Platforms". You can select Windows, Linux and Mac. Check with this: https://www.codeblocks.org/docs/build_targets.png

"this is not a duplicate of others i am asking for help on codeblocks." The thing is Code::Blocks is an environment that sits atop a compiler, so the only difference you'll see between any cross compiler-based answers and what you want is configuring code::blocks to use a different set of build tools.

I'm with catnip on this although I prefer VMWare and Ubuntu. Nothing beats testing stuff on the actual target OS - you can get misleading results with Windows ports when Unix and DOS disagree on eg capitalisation of source or include file names.
